# How do I display an image before the first post of the loop when I'm using get_template_part?

Tags: loop, content, theme-twenty-eleven, count, get-template-part

I have used $count before, but never run into this problem.  I cannot get it to work.  I have limited php background, so please be patient with me!  Here is the $count setup code:

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : // Start the Loop ?>
    <?php $count++; ?>      
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Within content.php - here is what I am trying to do:

```
<?php if ($count == 1) { ?>
    <section class="stories-title">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/stories-title.jpg" />
    </section>
<?php ;} ?>
```

Can anyone explain to me what's happening?  To the best of my knowledge, I'm running into an undefined variable issue, but I'm not sure how to fix this without breaking the $count... do the conditional statements and content have to be in the same file for $count to work?

UPDATE:  The issue (as described below) was with variable scope - the $count variable does not carry over when using template_part.  Here is the fixed code:

**functions.php**

```
// remember number (so we can count posts)

/**
 * Remember a number.
 *
 * @param  int|FALSE $add A number to add, or FALSE to reset the counter to 0 (zero).
 * @return int
 */

function wpse_count( $add = 0 )
{
    static $counter = 0;

    if ( FALSE === $add )
        $counter = 0;
    else
        $counter += (int) $add;

    return $counter;
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php wpse_count( FALSE ); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : // Start the Loop ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php wpse_count( 1 ); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**content.php**

```
    <?php if (count_posts() == 1) { ?>
        <section class="stories-title">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/stories-title.jpg" />
        </section>
    <?php ;} ?>
```

**Additional Solution**

For a MUCH simpler solution to this problem, see a different answer below.  Just needed to use wp_query

```
<?php if ( $wp_query->current_post == 0 ) { ?>
```

No $counter needed.

Comment: This appears to be a **PHP** question, that is not specific to **WordPress**.

Comment: well - the problem is occurring specifically because of the get_template_part in the twentyeleven theme.  I realize others may have issues w/ undefined variables in settings outside of WP - this problem for me is very specific to wordpress functions & the template_part

Comment: I also don't see how the new title clarifies my question at all -- my problem is that the counter breaks when I call in a new template_part because the variables don't carry over.  Maybe that's exactly what the new title is saying.. but seems more general than my question

Comment: The problem is not specific to `get_template_part()`. That function is really just a fancy wrapper for the PHP `include()` function. The problem, which again is *not specific to WordPress*, is that variable scope does not pass through the PHP `include()` call.

Comment: I guess technically can't all questions can be reduced to php / html / mysql? This seemed to be a problem I only ran into when I switched to the twentyeleven loop style.  The main issue boils down to: I want to display an image ONLY before the 1st post.  I understand what you're saying - the problem is in PHP - but the solution I think might be specific to WP.  I defer to those who are more knowledgeable than me here.

Comment: *"The main issue boils down to: I want to display an image ONLY before the 1st post."* - Can I recommend that you rewrite your question, on **this** basis? The issue is that you've tried a solution/implementation, and are looking for a fix for your solution/implementation, rather than asking for a solution to your *underlying problem*. Asking **how to insert an image only before the first post in a Loop** is much more of a **WordPress-specific** question.

Comment: Completely understand.  My specific issue was solved - I'll mark an answer and update my question.  Thanks

Comment: I updated it - feel free to edit / move if you deem necessary.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `$count` is accessible in the scope of the current function only. So whatever happens inside `get_template_part()` cannot know that variable.

You could use a global variable, which is accessible everywhere as `$GLOBALS['count']`. But then you risk collisions with plugins and maybe other code.

I recommend a helper function for the `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Remember a number.
 *
 * @param  int|FALSE $add A number to add, or FALSE to reset the counter to 0 (zero).
 * @return int
 */
function wpse_count( $add = 0 )
{
    static $counter = 0;

    if ( FALSE === $add )
        $counter = 0;
    else
        $counter += (int) $add;

    return $counter;
}
```

You can use that function to remember any number you want. In your example that should look like this:

```
<?php 
// Reset the counter
wpse_count( FALSE );

if ( have_posts() ) : // Start the Loop

    while ( have_posts() ) : 
        the_post();
        wpse_count( 1 );
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;

endif; 
?>
```

And in the template part file you print the value without adding anything:

```
echo wpse_count();
```

Example in TwentyEleven’s `content-status.php`

```
<?php 
the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); 
echo 'Number: ' . wpse_count();
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm really revealing my limited php knowledge here - once I have this function setup, how do I implement in the template_part?

Comment: @timshutes See my update.

Comment: this solved it - post count is working correctly.  I just needed to fix my if statement.  I'll mark as the answer & update my question with the correct code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you could use the variable `$wp_query->current_post` to determine the position before the first post;
no `$counter` needed.

**content.php**

```
<?php if ( $wp_query->current_post == 0 ) { ?>
        <section class="stories-title">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/stories-title.jpg" />
        </section>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: +1. This is ultimately where I was trying to drive the OP. :)

Comment: I already marked an answer, but this is the solution I was looking for initially.  Chip was correct - I was pigeoned into my particular solution and should have asked a broader question.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing your `$count` variable outside of the part of the Loop that is running through the posts. You code needs to increment the counter inside the `while`.

```
$count = 0;
if ( have_posts() ) : // Start the Loop 
//     $count++;    
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      $count++; 
      echo $count."\n";
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

Then use one of the options in the other answers to solve the variable scope problem.

Comment: I fixed this.  working on the var scope issue

Answer (score 0):

How about using the $GLOBALS['count'] to make it surely available everywhere.

Comment: can you explain a little more how you would use this?

Comment: This solution sounds a little dangerous to me.. possibly getting in the way of plugins, etc.  anything simpler?